# How to get the updated selected option of dropdownlist in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have dropdownlist asp.net server control where options are bind using C#.

Based on user input, I am setting the selected dropdown list control.

```
<select name="cars" id="ddlCars" runat="server">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

 $("#txtCarChoice").blur(function () {
            var car=  parseFloat($(this).val());
            if(car > 0.00)
            {
                $("#ddlCars").val("volvo");
                $("#ddlCars option[value='volvo']").prop("selected", "selected");
            }

        });
```

In UI it is updated as per requirement, but while in C#, the below line returns the first option of dropdownlist.

```
var selectedCar = ddlCars.SelectedValue.Text;
```

selectedCar is always getting the first value i.e., Volvo

How do I get the updated selected option in back end (C#)?

Comment: What is `ddlCars`? Is it an aspnet DropDownList or a generic control? What is `txtCarChoice`? How does `ddlCars` get populated with data? Your question is lacking much info. But my guess would be that you are binding data to `ddlCars` without an IsPostBack check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Volvo is the default, but here's some jQuery code to resolve the issue.

It's filtering the options

```
 $("#txtCarChoice").blur(function () {
        var car=  parseFloat($(this).val());
        if(car > 0.00)
        {
             $('#ddlCars option')
.filter(function(i, e) { return $(e).text() == "Volvo"}).prop('selected', true);
        }

    });
```